# Multiple temp table queries in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have this set of MySQL queries I need to execute using a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 SELECT * FROM tree;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 SELECT * FROM tree;
SELECT level_1 FROM t1
UNION
SELECT level_2 FROM t2;
```

The multiple temp tables is (in case someone's wondering) a trick to work around MySQL not letting you use the same table twice in a query.

Now there are two problems I need a solution for:

1. Running multiple statements, including both DML & DDL
2. Running temp table queries; `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` gives you a
   different connection for every call, hence you will lose all temp
   tables between calls.

TIA.

Comment: Doesn't MySQL allow multiple tables in same query?  I think it does. Do you mean the Java MySQL wrapper doesn't allow?

Comment: @SiddharthaRT Do you mean multiple statements separated by semicolons?

Comment: I don't think NamedParameterJdbcTemplate lets you do that

Comment: I think `SELECT t1.level_1, t2.level_2 from tree t1 join tree t2 on t1.id = t2.id;` is valid MySQL. I dont know if it's allowed in NamedParameterJDBC.

Comment: @SiddharthaRT Firstly, you missed the temp table DDL. Secondly, you're retrieving it as two columns, whereas my query returns a single columns with unique values from all levels